# How to get the row sum of 2 dimensional array and rank them from highest to lowest?

Tags: java, arrays

I have here code for getting the row sum but the answer is wrong, and I don't know how to get the ranks.

```
int[][] ranks = {
      {29, 20, 7, 25, 32, 6}, 
      {20, 31, 17, 31, 32, 26},
      {22, 30, 16, 32, 22, 15}
};
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
{
    sum = sum + ranks[i][j];
}
System.out.println(sum);    
        }
```

Comment: what is the ideal answer? i just ran your code it is giving row sum correctly  119,276,413

Comment: the second row sum should be 157, and 137 for the third row sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] ranks = { { 29, 20, 7, 25, 32, 6 }, { 20, 31, 17, 31, 32, 26 }, { 22, 30, 16, 32, 22, 15 } };
        int sum[] = new int[ranks.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ranks[i].length; j++) {
                sum[i] += ranks[i][j];
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of row " + (i + 1) + " = " + sum[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(sum);
        System.out.println("Sum of ranks in highest to lowest: ");
        for (int i = sum.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(sum[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sum of row 1 = 119
Sum of row 2 = 157
Sum of row 3 = 137
Sum of ranks in highest to lowest: 
157
137
119
```

**Notes:**

1. Use an `int` array (`int sum[]` in the code given above) to store the sum of each row.
2. The default value on each index of an `int` array is `0`.
3. To sort an array in ascending order, you can use `java.util.Arrays::sort`. There can be many other ways as well.
4. Display the sorted array from last to the first element in order to display the numbers from highest to lowest.
5. Last but not the least, use `length` attribute of the array instead of using fixed numbers like `3` or `6` to limit the iterations.